# "Expression is always false" when casting with AS

Tags: c#, casting, compiler-warnings

I get the compiler warning

> Expression is always false

on this code

```
void Test(Part part) {
   var wire = part as Wire;    
   if (wire == null) return;

   if (part == null) {  //here I get the warning
      ....
   }
}
```

But if the cast to `Wire` fails and results in `null` does not mean `part` is `null` too.

Is this a wrong warning or am I wrong?

<sub>`Wire` is a subclass of `Part`</sub>

Comment: This can happen if `Part` class inherits from `Wire` class. It's unclear what kind of relationships there are between classes. (in SO questions, I never assume anything - I've seen too much :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But if the cast to Wire fails and results in null does not mean part is null too.

No, but the reverse is true - if `part` is null, then `wire` will *definitely* be null, so you'll already have returned... hence the warning. (I'm assuming you don't change the value of `part` in the intervening code.)

Basically, you've got a stricter check earlier - it's a bit like this:

```
int value = ...;

if (value < 10)
{
    return;
}
...
if (value < 0)
{
    return;
}
```

If `value` is less than 0, then it's definitely less than 10, so we won't get past the first check.

Hopefully that's a simpler condition to understand - then apply that to the relationship between `part` and `wire` and when they can have null values.

Comment: If I understand you right, then the warning should actually be *Expression **might** always be false*, right? Because if `part != null` then `wire` might be `null` or not.

Comment: @juergend: No, it *is* always false by the time execution reaches it. There's no way of getting into that second `if` statement's body. If `part` is not-null, then the condition is false, by definition. To put it another way - under what circumstance do you expect that second `if` statement to do anything useful? Saying "if `part != null`", you're already in the case that the condition is false...

Comment: @juergend: proof by contradiction: assume `part == null`. Then it must be the case that `wire == null` (because `null as Wire == null`). But we know `wire != null`, because the `if` would have returned. Therefore `part != null`.